# I am facing issue while printing the size of list in eclipse for selenium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I am facing issue while printing the size of list:

```
System.out.println("no of list", +list.size());
```

And the error is:
 `"the method println(int)" in the type printstream is not applicable for the arguments(string, int)`

Here is my code:

```
package newpackage;


import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

public class TagNme_Locator {

public static void main(String[] args) {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Program [enter image description here][1]Files\\selenium\\IEDriver\\IEDriverServer.exe");
 WebDriver driver= new InternetExplorerDriver();
 driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/");
 List <WebElement> list= driver.findElements(By.tagName("div"));    
 System.out.println("no of list", +list.size());
 for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
     System.out.println(list.get(i).getText());
 }
}
}
```

Comment: Remove the `,`.

Comment: The comma means you’re trying to put in two arguments but it only accepts one. As said above, remove the comma or move within the quotes.

Comment: Thanks.. i am new to selenium and java. thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you're using a comma instead of the needed concatenation operator, which is `+` in Java. I'm not sure if the comma was intended, based on the `+list.size()`, but you never know.

Errors mean a **lot** if you know how to interpret them, this one meaning that you can't use two arguments of type `String` and `int` with a method defined for an argument of `int`.

Comment: thanks. it is workingnow